# Is there a way to see what command are run on your computer?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, shell, shell-script

I was wondering how I could see the actions that are done on my computer but on my cmd prompt.

For example: Imagine I click on the shortcut Google Chrome on my desktop, then this will appear on my cmd prompt (or anywhere else):

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe`

modulo the - and -- arguments but that was just for the example.

Comment: "then this will appear on my cmd prompt (or anywhere else):" - A user running an application with a shortcut is not logged.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like that described here:

https://eventlogxp.com/blog/process-tracking-with-event-log-explorer/

It describes how to configure the logging of these events:

> use Group Policy Editor (gpedit.msc) or Local Security Policy (secpol.msc). You should configure Security Settings -> Audit Policy -> Audit Process Tracking or use Advanced Audit Policy Configuration -> System Audit Policy -> Detailed Tracking.

And then it shows you what you should see in the Windows event log, including the process name and command line:

> New Process Name (Process Name) the full path to the executable.

> Process Command Line defines a command line used to start the process.
> It includes the full path to the executable along with command line
> parameters. By default, Process Command Line is empty (because it may
> contains sensitive data like passwords). To enable command line
> logging you should enable policy “Include command line in process
> creation events”. This policy is available at Administrative Templates
> -> System -> Audit Process Creation.

I hope that's helpful.

Comment: Thanks but I didn't find out how to achieve my goal with this process :/

Comment: Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Well not so far, I jst got the app open after I use "win jey+R" into gpedit.msc. But then I only have computer configuration and user configuration and I don't know where I have to go to see other informations. I don't see Security settings neither.

Comment: Each of those ("Computer Configuration" and "User Configuration") have subordinate items that you can expose by clicking on the tiny triangle to the left of the text.  You'll want to go under Computer Configuration.  You can explore some screenshots starting with googling "local policy computer audit".

Comment: Now I can see all the list of "Audit account...",..., "Audit process tracking" etc but I don't know what I have to activate and where do I see the results after that